# Getting new facebook comment on old post with fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

For an application which I'm writing im polling a facebook page with following fql query

```
select post_id from stream where source_id = {mypageid} AND updated_time > {unixtime since last noticed update}
```

It works great as long as the post which the comment got written to is not too old. However if the post is to old my query doesn't return any data. I didn't figured out yet what the specific timespan is when my query is working.

Does anyone know how to avoid this problem or how to modify my query to get all post with a new comment since the last time my query was executed?

Thanks in advance...